# Graphite - Gather metrics only from active service instances

Tags: grafana, graphite, micrometer

Lets say my spring microservice processes data. Every time a successful processing event occurs, for metrics, I update the micrometer counter. This is registered to a Graphite Registry.

```
registry = new GraphiteMeterRegistry(new GraphiteConfiguration(), Clock.SYSTEM, HierarchicalNameMapper.DEFAULT);
Counter counter = Counter.builder("process").tag("status","success").register(registry);
```

So far, it sounds good. But what if I have to create and deploy multiple instances of my service?

How do I get the aggregated count of all successful events from all the instances?

To illustrate my case further, I log the counter.count() value on each increment. Here is what i see ->

```
<Instance 1> <time> <package-name> Count :122
<Instance 2> <time> <package-name> Count :53
```

So when I run the graphite query on graphana -

```
process.status.success.count
```

I tend to get the random count from either of these instances.

What I need is a query like -

```
process.service-instance.status.success.count
```

so that I can run a summarize() function in the end.

**Update**
Now I'm able to source data from all instances by getting the service instance ID. But that presents a new problem - Since I restart my services time and again, and my service-id changes every time, how do I source data from ONLY ACTIVE services?

Since process.*.status.success.count represents aggregate count of ALL services - dead or alive

Comment: You can remove netflix-eureka from tags. Question is not related to eureka.

Comment: You can remove spring-cloud as well. There's nothing in this question specific to spring-cloud.

Comment: removed tags as suggested

Answer (score 0):

Never use instance ids for aggregation. When instances restart, instance ids will change. (Use instance-id for logging/debugging/record-keeping purpose only.)

Use service-id for aggregation.

For micrometer, you can add service-name in common tags.

```
registry.config().commonTags("service", "xyz-service");
```

Common tags are defined at registry level and every metric associated with that registry will have common tags added to it.

And, for dead or alive situation: The metric was pushed when the instance was alive. So if you want to know how many times *some step* ran, you'll need to consider that count.

To source data from active instances, use time-filter. That will return data pushed by instances that were alive in that duration (Why? Because dead instances do not push metrics).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I get the part with common tags and have already implemented it. However, how do i aggregate it service-id wise? Let's say I register a gauge to count events occuring in an entire day. I reset this gauge every midnight. I have 4 such service instances. How can I sum up the total events?

Comment: [The `WHERE` clause](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#the-where-clause) ?

Comment: Something like `SELECT SUM("value") FROM "metric" WHERE "serviceId" = "service-name"`?